# Установка идентификатора для List

Tags: c#, list, linq

Проблема заключается не в самом идентификаторе, а в его установке, в качестве уникального (например, на первое свободное место).

Например я имею коллекцию:

```
List<list_item> list = new List<list_item>();
List.Add(new list_item(???));
```

Где в конструкторе, я устанавливаю значение идентификатора:

```
public list_item(int id)
{
    public int item_id = id;
    string some_data;
}
```

Предполагается, что коллекция имеет достаточно большое число динамично обновляющихся (убывающих, поступающих) элементов, поэтому постоянный инкремент одного идентификатора не подойдет, а ручной перебор коллекции при поступающем элементе займет критичное число вычислительных ресурсов. Желательно чтобы тип его был int.

Возможно задача заключается в выборе первого свободного идентификатора составив linq запрос к списку элементов `list`.

Comment: ничего не понял, где вопрос то? что делать?

Comment: Устанавливать идентификатор на элемент списка )))

Comment: Spectre, List.Count никак не сможет дать уникальный индекс. Если же только последовательность постоянно пополняется. Если же удалить первых 10 эл-тов, по последующим 10 вставляемым пойдут неверные индексы.

Comment: да, я понял это, но я вижу только один способ - написать собственную реализацию коллекции, со специфической логикой добавления/удаления возможно с использованием словарей, чтобы контролировать уникальность индексов

Comment: Еще есть System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectIDGenerator, он генерирует уникальное значение Int64 для объекта. Но все же кажется, что вам подойдет и обычный инкремент.

Comment: (Археология) У меня есть сильное подозрение, что автору вопроса нужен на самом деле `HashSet<>`.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам следует воспользоваться методом GetHashCode().
Можете его переопределить для вашего класса, а можете воспользоваться стандартным.

Comment: [MSDN][1]:
>"Реализация метода GetHashCode по умолчанию не гарантирует уникальность возвращаемых для объекта значений...  Следовательно, реализацию такого метода по умолчанию не следует использовать для хэширования в качестве уникального идентификатора объекта."

Тем более уж при большом списке.


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: Дык я зачем по вашему посоветовал вам его переопределить. Уникальность стройте сами.

Comment: Guid uniq = new Guid();
Вам в помощь

Comment: гуиды гуидами, а инты намного удобнее и читабельнее

>Желательно чтобы тип его был int.

Comment: В большой коллекции размер занимаемых байт тоже важен, у Guid он в 4 раза больше. Да и выборка по элементу займет больше времени (хотя по поводу выборки я не уверен).

Comment: Ну Выделяйте автоинкремент Int32
При удалениии из списка заносите удаленный идентификатор в 
Dictionary
И будет вам счастье.
если словарь удаленных пуст выделяем новый, иначе берем из словаря первый и удаляем его из словаря

Comment: Конечно не проблема, если опустошится основная, опустошите коллекцию с незанятыми и начнете заново с 1 выделять номера

Answer (score 1):

Имхо, лучший вариант смотреть на индекс в коллекции как на индефикатор или использовать мапу, так как прятать ид внутри элемента нечего не даст при его поиске, прийдется переберать все и смотреть в каждый...

Comment: Индекс в коллекции... если удалить элемент "посередне" то у всех последующих индекс сменится, а добавляемому присвоится последний. В том то и дело, чтоб индекс был уникальным. А вот про мапы поподробней можно?

Comment: Так все зависит от задачи, возможно тебе будет достаточно уникальности ключей-индексов только для актуального списка. Насчет мапы - это коллекции, типа ключ-значение, где ты можешь как ключ ставить гуид или текущие время в мс, как уникальный индекс, а в значение - свой элемент, это даст преймущество в скорости при поиске. Если неошибаюсь в c# это коллекция Dictionary<key, value>, возможно есть, чтото универсальние для твокго случая...

Comment: Да Вы имеете ввиду Dictionary(TKey, TValue). Моя задача приблизительно и состоит в том чтобы присвоить TKey уникальный идентификатор типа int.

Comment: а long? если только int - так, на самый крайний случай, создай внешний счетчик int UID = 0 и просто при добавлении ключа - делай его инкремент.

Answer (score 0):

Да, это отличный вариант. Возможно стоило бы выделить в качестве ответа. Только небольшое но: когда основная коллекция опустошается до минимума, коллекция идентификаторов вырастает в противоположном направлении и хранит макс. число некогда элементов. Но это, я думаю не проблема.

```
List<int> identifier_list = new List<int>();
private int GetIdentifire()
{
    lock (identifier_list)
    {
        int id = identifier_list.FirstOrDefault();
        if (id == 0) return list.Count;
        else identifier_list.Remove(id);
        return id;
    }            
 }
```

Comment: `id==null` для типа `int`, вы уверены?

Comment: Да, конечно, Вы правы, int не может быть null, а значением по умолчанию OrDefault будет 0. Я потом вставлю рабочий код, этот так, для визуализации идеи был.